# addEventListener('resize' not working for div with relative size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a resize listener for a div with a relative size. The div has a `height: 100%` style on it, and I would like the event to fire when the pixel height of the div changes with its parent container. Here is my basic code:

## index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
<div class="foo"></foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

## main.css

```
.foo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

## main.js

```
document.querySelector(".foo").addEventListener("resize", () => {
  console.log("foo resize");
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  console.log("window resize");
});
```

When I resize the window, I get the expected "window resize" text in the console, but "foo resize" is never printed. Is there something else that I need to do to get the foo resize handler to fire?

Comment: [Resize Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). I think only currently on chrome, though there are some good [polyfills](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill)

Comment: I did see that, but I am targeting iOS safari, so I'd like to make sure my code works there.

Comment: The polyfills should five you the desired outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

The `resize` event is only fired on the `window` object. There's `ResizeObserver` in the making, allowing to observe the resizing of arbitrary elements, but [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) for it is still very scarce. There are however polyfills to mimic its behaviour, like [resize-observer-polyfill on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill).